# Calling new object functions between different Express functions?

Tags: node.js, class, oop, express, raspberry-pi

I am building a time-lapse camera web application using Raspberry Pi and the Raspberry Pi Camera Module. So far I have built a web application (using NodeJS, Express, AngularJS, and BootStrap 3) that can interact with the Raspberry Camera Module using an open source NodeJS module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/raspicam).

I have a global variable called "setting" that will always change whenever the user changes the camera settings:

```
var setting = {
    mode: "timelapse",
    output: "public/images/image%d.jpg", // image1, image2, image3, etc...
    encoding: "jpg",
    timelapse: 3000, // take a picture every 3 seconds
    timeout: 12000 // take a total of 4 pictures over 12 seconds
}
```

I have three functions in Express that can:

set Camera settings

```
exports.setCamera = function(req, res) {
    setting = {
        mode: req.body.mode,
        output: req.body.output,
        encoding: req.body.encoding,
        timelapse: req.body.timelapse,
        timeout: req.body.timeout
    }
    res.json(setting, 200);
    console.log('SET CAMERA - ' + JSON.stringify(setting));
}
```

start the Camera

```
exports.startCamera = function(req, res) {
    camera = new RaspiCam(setting);
    camera.on("start", function( err, timestamp ){
      console.log("timelapse started at " + timestamp);
    });

    camera.on("read", function( err, timestamp, filename ){
      console.log("timelapse image captured with filename: " + filename);
    });

    camera.on("exit", function( timestamp ){
      console.log("timelapse child process has exited");
      res.json(setting, 200);
    });

    camera.on("stop", function( err, timestamp ){
      console.log("timelapse child process has been stopped at " + timestamp);
    });

    camera.start();

    setTimeout(function(){
      camera.stop();
    }, setting.timeout + 1000);

    console.log('START CAMERA - ' + JSON.stringify(setting));
}
```

stop the Camera

```
exports.stopCamera = function(req, res) {
    camera.stop();
    res.json(setting, 200);
    console.log('STOP CAMERA - ' + JSON.stringify(setting));
}
```

As you can see in the "startCamera" function, I am creating a new RaspiCam object called "camera" that passes in the global variable "setting" (which can always change). When the camera object is created, I am also creating "start", "read", "exist", and "stop" functions for it. The problem is that since I am not setting the camera object as a global variable, when the user decides to click Stop halfway during the session, the "stopCamera" function gets called but it does not know what camera.stop() is and says it is undefined. Is there a way I can allow the "stopCamera" function to know what camera.stop() is (which was created in the "startCamera" function)?

Sorry if this is confusing, I don't know how else to describe my problem.. :(

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just accept the settings in the startCamera function and get rid of setCamera? Creating requests that must be called in a certain order is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: I am not accepting the settings in the startCamera function because the startCamera will be specifically used for the "Start" button on the web interface. The setCamera function will be used on the Settings page where user will be able to make edits to the settings. I also plan on storing the setting object somewhere else in an actual database so then I will be able to call getCamera to get the settings. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with how this is architected, but the simple solution to your question is check to see if the camera object has been initialized.

```
exports.stopCamera = function(req, res) {
    if(camera && typeof(camera.stop) == "function") {
        camera.stop();
        console.log('STOP CAMERA - ' + JSON.stringify(setting));    
    }

    res.json(setting, 200); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping Timothy! The problem I have right now is that I am not able to access camera.stop() in the stopCamera function. This tells me there is a scoping problem where only the startCamera function is able to recognize the camera functions. I would like the stopCamera function to call camera.stop() as well :)

Comment: Are these exports in the same module?

Comment: I provided a JSFiddle so you can take a look at my timelapse.js file!

http://jsfiddle.net/L3B92/

Comment: Then the code above should work. camera.stop will only work after camera has been created. That's why I add a conditional around calling camera.stop. It will only be called if camera isn't null and has a stop function.